# Python tab completion without defining arguments directly in class as required by cmd

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-3.9

We have a command line interface for our program written in python.  We want to add tab completion to this interface.  the cmd module seems the obvious choice, except for one problem.  It requires all the possible arguments to be defined right in the class in the form of methods.

We have a number of commands in our CLI, and modules can add new commands specific to them in a sort of plug in interface.  We do this by having a command class for each potential argument that defines the command, it's description and behaviors etc.  This has proven cleaner and more flexible for us and I don't want to change this by trying to throw dozens of methods in one class; especially since I won't know all the possible commands that can be run since some are dependent on third party modules that will be added later.

So is there a way to get pretty tab completion without having to predefine every possible command ahead of time in the cmd class directly?

Ideally we would also like to allow tab completion of some arguments, not just commands as well.  I'd love to also be able to capture a few hotkeys; but that's not important enough to reinvent the wheel with everything a terminal does for us if I can't find a third party tool that makes adding handling of hotkeys easier.  This has to run on both Linux and Windows so I don't want any OS dependent terminal hacking either.

Can I get the CMD module to work without predefining commands directly as methods to a class?  Failing that are there any other 3rd party python tools which might support a more complex command line behavior then the cmd module allows?

Comment: [`click` supports generating completions](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/) if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is very dynamic. You can add a new method to a class with `setattr(the_class, "the_method_name", the_method_definition)`. You can also use a `class X:` statement inside a function (the class will be stored in a local variable). This is all you need.

Use your dynamic plugin interface to create a commands dictionary, where the keys are command names prefixed with "do_" and the values are callables (lambdas, functions, objects with `__call__`). Then iterate the dictionary and use setattr() to assemble them into a class.

Full example:

```py
import cmd

# You can implement commands with a normal function
def aaaabbbb(shell, arg):
    """It has a doc string"""
    print("Hello from aaaabbbb %r" % arg)

    # It is even possible to add more commands dynamically if you really want to
    shell.__class__.do_ccdd = lambda shell, arg: print("Hello from dynamically added ccdd %r" % arg)

# You can implement commands with a callable (object with __call__ method)
class Cccc:
    """It has a class doc string"""
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print("Hello from cccc %r" % arg)

def complete_cccc(shell, text, line, begidx, endidx):
    return [w for w in ['xxxxxx', 'xxxyyy', 'zzzzzz'] if w.startswith(text)]

commands = {
   # You can implement commands with a lambda
   'do_aaaaaaa': lambda shell, arg: print("Hello from aaaaaaa %r" % arg),
   'do_aaaabbbb': aaaabbbb,
   'do_cccc': Cccc(),

   # You can define completion for a specific command's arguments
   'complete_cccc': complete_cccc,
}

# *** Here comes the important part! ***

def main():
    class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):
        def do_EOF(self, arg):
            print()
            return True

    for name, value in commands.items():
        setattr(MyShell, name, value)

    MyShell().cmdloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will give you completion of command names, a built in `help` command that lists them, and you can define completion of arguments for a specific command.

(By the way: in most circumstances it would be enough to setattr on the instance. `my_instance = MyShell(); setattr(my_instance, 'method_name', definition)`. But cmd internally uses `dir(self.__class__)`.)

But also consider reading [the cmd module's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/cmd.py) directly. It sounds to me that you might be outgrowing what it provides. Reimplementing it yourself might not be as hard as you think. And it would give you full control.